# Handle specific error in bash

Tags: bash, error-handling, exit-status, stderr

As a part of my script, I want to publish package to nuget feed:

`dotnet nuget push package.1.2.3.nupkg --source "mysource" --api-key "mykey"`

The command may print `error: 409 already contains version 1.2.3` and exit with code 1. This is perfectly fine in my context, but it makes the whole script fail. I want to wrap this command with something, that will swallow non-zero exit code if specific error appears in stdout, but to bubble up non-zero exit code if it does not appear. What can I use for my task?

Comment: What pipeline? How does it fail? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott I just replaced `CI pipeline` with `script` to be more general, is that fine to you?

Comment: My point is that a non-zero exit code doesn’t *cause* a whole script to fail unless you have done `set -e` (or you are testing the code and explicitly exiting). So, no, you haven’t really answered my question “How does it fail?”

Comment: Is it the combination of the output *and* the exit status=1 that you need, or can you ignore every exit status of 1?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I did not check error code on other cases when error happens, but I can assume that it is always 1, so I have to handle code 1 in combination with this specific output/

Comment: I just noticed a specific version number in there; should the output require `1.2.3` or be flexible with any version number? Please edit the question to specify; thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller no, I can omit version and just live with `error: 409 already contains version`

Comment: @Scott yeah, you are right, but the failure of containing script/CI pipeline/etc is not really important to my question, I just need to "substitute" command return code from 1 to 0 if some specific text appears in stdout. CI pipeline stuff is just provided for context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script catches stdout and stderr and prints it to stdout again if exit code is 0 and to stderr otherwise.

If the string contains "error: 409 already contains version", then the function returns 0 and the original exit code otherwise.

```
#!/bin/bash

function do_nuget ()
{
        # save stdout and stderr
        out=$(dotnet nuget push "$1" --source "$2" --api-key "$3" 2>&1)
        exitcode=$?

        # if out is not empty...
        if [ -n "$out" ]; then
                if [ $exitcode -eq 0 ]; then
                        # echo to stdout
                        echo "$out"
                else
                        # echo to stderr
                        echo "$out" >&2
                fi
        fi
        if [ "$out" != "${out/error: 409 already contains version}" ]; then
                return 0
        fi
        return $exitcode
}
do_nuget "package.1.2.3.nupkg" "mysource" "mykey"
echo "got exit code: $?"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you after something more complicated than this?

```
emsg=$(your_command ... 2>&1) ||
    case $emsg in
    *"ignorable error condition"*) ;; # do nothing
    *) printf >&2 '%s\n' "$emsg"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
```

As a function:

```
# usage ignore pattern cmd [args ...]
ignore(){(
    pat=$1; shift; exec 3>&1
    emsg=$("$@" 2>&1 >&3 3>&-) || { e=$? &&
        case $emsg in
        $pat) ;; # ignore
        *) printf >&2 '%s\n' "$emsg"; exit "$e" ;;
        esac
    }
)}
```

You'll have to get rid of the extra fd juggling if your program is writing its `error: 409 ..` message to *stdout*, not to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `|| true` to the line in your script i.e.

```
dotnet nuget push package.1.2.3.nupkg --source "mysource" --api-key "mykey" || true
```

as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11231970/1671398) answer on Stackoverflow

Comment: yeah, but i think it will swallow every error, instead of just the single one I want swallowed, isn't it?

Comment: You are right, I mistakenly thought you wanted the script to continue regardless of which error happened.